# Pandas bringing in data from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am trying to bring data from a dataframe which is mapping table into another dataframe using the following, however I get an error 'x' is not defined, what am I doing wrong pls?

Note for values not in the mapping table (China/CN) I would just like the value to be blank or nan. If there are values in the mapping table that are not in my data - I don't want to include them.

```
import pandas as pd

languages = {'Language': ["English", "German", "French", "Spanish"],
            'countryCode': ["EN", "DE", "FR", "ES"]
            }

countries = {'Country': ["Australia", "Argentina", "Mexico", "Algeria", "China"],
             'countryCode': ["EN", "ES", "ES", "FR", "CN"]
            }

language_map = pd.DataFrame(languages)
data = pd.DataFrame(countries)

def language_converter(x):
    return language_map.query(f"countryCode=='{x}'")['Language'].values[0]

data['Language'] = data['countryCode'].apply(language_converter(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.DataFrame.merge):

```
data.merge(language_map, how='left')
```

Output:

```
     Country countryCode Language
0  Australia          EN  English
1  Argentina          ES  Spanish
2     Mexico          ES  Spanish
3    Algeria          FR   French
4      China          CN      NaN
```

Comment: what if my data has codes that aren't in the mapping table? using merge it drops those rows off. I'd like to retain the rows (the above is a mock up of the real data)

Comment: Just add the parameter `how=left` to `merge` function -- that is enough to keep all rows of dataframe `data`.

Comment: also the column names are different. In reality the two are different series with partial overlaps. I want to return those overlaps..but keeping those that don't

Comment: Try `how=outer` instead.

Comment: @NovicePythoncharmer, if you have an additional significant nuances - reflect them in your question

Comment: it would be great if a solution can be found using the method I started with, that would help my understand the map method

Answer (score 0):

`.apply` accepts a callable object, but you've passed `language_converter(x)` which is already a function call with undefined `x` variable as `apply` is not *applied* yet.

A valid usage is: `.apply(language_converter)`.

But next, you'll have another error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` as some country codes may not be found (which breaks the indexing `.values[0]`).

If proceeding with your starting approach a valid version would look as below:

```
def language_converter(x):
    lang = language_map[language_map["countryCode"] == x]['Language'].values
    return lang[0] if lang.size > 0 else np.nan

data['Language'] = data['countryCode'].apply(language_converter)
print(data)
```

---

```
     Country countryCode Language
0  Australia          EN  English
1  Argentina          ES  Spanish
2     Mexico          ES  Spanish
3    Algeria          FR   French
4      China          CN      NaN
```

---

**But**, instead of defining and applying `language_converter` it's much simpler and straightforward to map country codes explicitly with just:

```
data['Language'] = data['countryCode'].map(language_map.set_index("countryCode")['Language'])
```